# Label Outlet On Custom UICollectionViewCell In Swift Causing Optional.None Crash

Tags: uicollectionview, swift, uicollectionviewcell, ios8

I have a collectionViewController that I want to display a bunch of custom UICollectionViewCells with some labels on them. Unfortunately whenever I try and access the custom UICollectionViewCell's label it causes a crash with:

**Console**

> fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None

**Window**

> Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

I'm trying to access the label like so:

```
cell.name.text = names[indexPath!.item]
```

Perhaps this comes from my outlet label being nil? But looking around for answers nothing has worked, and because I'm not really sure what the issue is adding ?/! in my code isn't really helping.

**MyCustomUICollectionViewController**

```
class ScrambledTextCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    var names: String[] = ["Anna", "Alex", "Brian", "Jack"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Register cell classes
        self.collectionView.registerClass(MyCustomCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView?) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView?, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView?, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewCell? {
        var cell = collectionView?.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyCustomCollectionViewCell

        cell.name.text = names[indexPath!.item]

        return cell
    }
}
```

**MyCustomCollectionViewCell**

```
class MyCustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var name: UILabel
    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)                
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is the error occurring on? Have you added an exception breakpoint to try to find where the error is?

Comment: cell.name.text = names[indexPath!.item] gets a Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: Maybe I'm being stupid but you haven't defined the `var names` outside the scope of `viewDidLoad`. Surely you should define the var... `var names` in the scope of the whole object not just viewDidLoad.

Comment: Ah whoops, thats because i've simplified the code for Stack Overflow and that array shouldn't be set there, i'll fix it, but it isn't the issue.

Comment: "Perhaps this comes from my outlet label being nil?" If `cell.name` is indeed `nil`, that's your problem. Can you log its value right before your crashing line?

Comment: println(cell.word) returns nil, so you seem to be onto the answer, but how/where would I make it not nil?

Comment: Try replace exclamation mark with question tag names[indexPath?.item]

Comment: I don't believe this would fix my issue, it will crash even if i directly set the label cell.name.text = "Hello". What confuses me is that i've made a UITableView use a custom UITableViewCell in much the same way without issue.

Comment: im having the same issue, my label and imageview is returning nil from a custom collection cell. I've check the connects and class name is correct but no luck. any solution everyone?

Comment: This is so simple but I cannot get it to work either. Swift is giving the the SWIFTS !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165195/why-is-uicollectionviewcells-outlet-nil)

Remove, `self.collectionView.registerClass(MyCustomCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)`

Read link for detailed reason why